# "Down the shore" versus "at the beach"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between *down the shore* and *at the beach*? Does the latter imply  you are physically on the beach?

Comment: Did you mean down _at_ the shore?  That would make the two equal.  Otherwise, _down the shore_ is a directional phrase like _up the river_ or _over yonder_.

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 But informally people might well say "down the shore" - like "down the village", or "down the pub".

Comment: "Down the shore" would match "down the beach."

Anything else would not match.

What were you really Asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a New Jersey expression and refers to heading down south to any of the beach towns on the New Jersey shoreline.

Answer (score 6):

Consider that "the shore" in NJ was largely developed as resort communities for Philadelphia and New York during the summer months: in fact some resorts were built and owned by the railroads which took people there.

The beach is only part of the experience which included other attractions. In addition, many people have and had summer homes there.

"The Shore" is more a region than a location.

Comment: Would shore be capitalized when used in this way? (Being a midwesterner, I had never heard of the phrase *down the shore*. Learned something new!)

Comment: Yes. What you are saying I think is that "beach" has a different meaning to "shore". Some shores don't have beaches. And some beaches are not at a shore - there is for example an artificial, created beach in central London - or there was. I'm not sure if it is still there.

Answer (score 4):

My impression is that *"down the shore"* is what some people from New York/New Jersey/Philadelphia say to mean they're going to the Jersey Shore, which is south of New York. It was also [the name of a sitcom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_the_Shore) set in Belmar, a town on the Jersey Shore. If you're in New York City, and you go to a beach on Long Island, that is **not** *"down the shore"*.

Answer (score 1):

"down the ..." is just a New Jersey idiom.  The reason that it is "the shore" instead of the beach is that the Jersey shore is primarily made up of barrier islands which have both a bayside and an oceanside (a beach) and other amenities like boardwalks, rides, bars, junk food, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom in the mix here is to say "Down" instead of "On the shore" which is why it may sound strange, just as "down the town" should be "in the town". (And also the difference between beach and shore).

Here in Ireland it has resulted in an even more twisted geographical references, such as "Down the north" or "Up to Dublin" (Dublin being in the south or east).

"At the beach" would usually imply being at the sandy place where the sea meets land, "On the shore" would usually be used to differentiate with being "On the sea".

One could also possibly say "At the shore" which would indicate that one was at the point where sea meets land, irrespective of whether it was a beach or not, a beach generally being a gradient of loose particles such as sand or pebbles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it means anywhere else but here in New Jersey the nuance is exemplified in this sentence:

> I live at the beach but my friend lives in Philly and comes down the shore on weekends.

Where "at the beach" and "down the shore" refer to any of the Jersey shore towns/neighborhoods.